# VBA replacing text not keeping the replacement text's formatting and randomly applying uppercase formatting

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to get this code to work but it keeps randomly uppercasing the entire sentences I am trying to replace the "ID's" with. I am using ID00 numbers to replace text. Sometimes the replacement will be all caps. I cannot figure out how to keep the casing that it should be.
An example would be: ID001 to be replaced with "This is an example. I want this." It's doing this: "THIS IS AN EXAMPLE. I WANT THIS."

```
With Selection.Find
.ClearFormatting


chunks = Round(Len(replace) / 250, 0)                   
If Len(replace) Mod 250 > 0 Then chunks = chunks + 1      
If chunks = 1 Then
    .Execute FindText:=search, ReplaceWith:=replace, replace:=wdReplaceAll
Else

    .Execute FindText:=search, ReplaceWith:="{1}", replace:=wdReplaceAll

    ' Replace the text in chunks of less than 255 characters
    For i = 1 To chunks


        chunk = Mid(replace, ((i - 1) * 250) + 1, 250)


        If i < chunks Then chunk = chunk & "{" & (i + 1) & "}"

        .Execute FindText:="{" & i & "}", ReplaceWith:=chunk, replace:=wdReplaceAll
    Next i

End If
```

End With

Comment: Please provide some sample text for testing as well as an example of the "good" and "bad" results so that we can understand.

Comment: I have edited the original to include an example. Basically, it is just capitalizing every letter in the replacement text. It seems to be happening only on certain phrases that I have though. Unsure why.

Comment: If code uses `Selection.Find` instead of `Range.Find` then Find will work with the settings last used in the Find/Replace dialog box. Possibly, ALL CAPS formatting has been used for replacement and is affecting the result? Might be a good idea to stick a `Replacement.ClearFormatting` in there. And/Or modify the code to use `Find` with a `Range` object.

Answer (score 0):

Try using MatchCase:=False. For example:

```
.Execute FindText:=search, ReplaceWith:=replace, MatchCase:=False, Replace:=wdReplaceAll
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a old post, but i had the same problem.. 
After playing around with it for a while, this helped me.

I tried with both no formatting on the replacement text and with specific formatting not to be all caps - Still came out all caps..

I found out that, if the whole text i search for is upper case, it will change it all to uppercase. If first letter in searched text is uppercase the first in replaced text will be uppercase. No matter which formating you put on.

I had a text called "C-PTFE CIP" and wanted in some scenarios to add extra to it, which all came out as all caps. My fix was to add a bit more of the text "ix C-PTFE CIP" and just add the "ix " to my replacement text. Now everything comes out as i want, not only all lowercase, but as i'd like it.

So for your case, change the "ID" to "id" if possible, or if you're lucky as me, to be able to add some more of the text.

Hope this can help others in the future. I have no idea why the formattings doesn't overrule the searched text.. Maybe other settings in the document?